# How change the format of following xml file using cakephp or Php?

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to change the format of following xml file using cakephp or Php using DOM element.

```
<child>
 <Lunchmenu>
   <id>1</id>
   <lunch_date>2013-10-25</lunch_date>
   <class_id>1</class_id>
   <batch_id/>
   <school_id>1</school_id>
   <Eatable>
   <eatable_name>Noodles</eatable_name>
   </Eatable>
 </Lunchmenu>
 <Lunchmenu>
  <id>2</id>
  <lunch_date>2013-10-24</lunch_date>
  <class_id/>
  <batch_id/>
  <school_id>1</school_id>
  <Eatable>
   <eatable_name>Apples</eatable_name>
  </Eatable>
 </Lunchmenu>
 <Lunchmenu>
    <id>2</id>
    <lunch_date>2013-10-24</lunch_date>
    <class_id/>
    <batch_id/>
    <school_id>1</school_id>
    <Eatable>
    <eatable_name>Orange</eatable_name>
    </Eatable>
  </Lunchmenu>
</child>
```

To

```
<child>
 <Lunchmenu>
   <id>1</id>
   <lunch_date>2013-10-25</lunch_date>
   <class_id>1</class_id>
   <batch_id/>
   <school_id>1</school_id>
   <Eatable>
   <eatable_name>Noodles</eatable_name>
   </Eatable>
 </Lunchmenu>
<Lunchmenu>
  <id>2</id>
  <lunch_date>2013-10-24</lunch_date>
  <class_id/>
  <batch_id/>
  <school_id>1</school_id>
    <Eatable>
     <eatable_name>Apples</eatable_name>
    </Eatable>
    <Eatable>
     <eatable_name>Orange</eatable_name>
    <Eatable>
 </Lunchmenu>
```

I tried but no success.

Comment: What did you tried? Show us your piece of code!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I will use this PHP function : [simplexml_load_string](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

```php
$xml_parsed = simplexml_load_string('<your xml>');
```

And then, use it like this :

```
//1st regroup lunchmenu by DATE or by ID I don't know what you want
$lunch = array();
foreach($xml_parsed->Lunchmenu as $lunchmenu) {
   $lunch[$lunchmenu->id][] = $lunchmenu;
}
//Then reform XML
foreach($lunch as $lunchmenus) {
    $lunchmenu = $lunchmenus[0];
    $finalXML .= "<Lunchmenu>
                  <id>".$lunchmenu->id."</id>
                  <lunch_date>".$lunchmenu->lunch_date."</lunch_date>
                  <class_id>".$lunchmenu->class_id."</class_id>
                  <batch_id/>
                  <school_id>".$lunchmenu->school_id."</school_id>";
    foreach($lunchmenus as $lunchmenu) {
        $finalXML .= "<Eatable>
                     <eatable_name>".$lunchmenu->eatable_name."</eatable_name>
                      </Eatable>";
    }
    $finalXML .= '</Lunchmenu>';
}
$finalXML = '<child>';
$finalXML .= '</child>';

echo $finalXML;
```

I haven't testing anything... It's just to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XSLT Processor function of PHP to transform from one XML format to another.

More information can be found here:

http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php

Alternatively, a more labor intensive way would be to use XMLReader and XMLWriter Class to programmatically format the XML how you need it to be.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php

James